# pd.info() output has no spacing between columns

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

My Jupyter notebook output for `renamedBostonData.info()` is:

[image: screenshot showing info table without spacing between columns]

I am facing this issue with `value_counts()` as well.
Dataframes are also printed properly.

instead of Jupyter Lab output:

[image: screenshot showing table with proper spacing]

Is there a setting that has been changed? If so how to correct?

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). But if it looks different, by all means keep the screenshots.

Comment: Your examples show two different dataframes. The first one has relatively long and non-uniform column names which make the output look worse.